# std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 doesn't convert utf-8 to utf-16 in big-endian

Tags: c++, c++11, utf-8

I converted a string in utf-8 encoding to string in utf-16, by using `wstring_convert` & `codecvt_utf8_utf16`

here is the sample code I tested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>

std::u16string UTF8ToWide(const std::string& utf_str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;
    return converter.from_bytes(utf_str);
}

void DisplayBytes(const void* data, size_t len)
{
    const uint8_t* src = static_cast<const uint8_t*>(data);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        printf("%.2x ", src[i]);
    }
}

// the content is:"你好 hello chinese test 中文测试"
std::string utf8_s = "\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd hello chinese test \xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95";

int main()
{
    auto ss = UTF8ToWide(utf8_s);
    DisplayBytes(ss.data(), ss.size() * sizeof(decltype(ss)::value_type));
    return 0;
}
```

according to [reference manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_mode), **the default argument of `std::codecvt_mode` in the facet `codecvt_utf8_utf16` is big-endian**.

However, the test program displays bytes as follows

> 60 4f 7d 59 20 00 68 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00 6f 00 20 00 63 00 68 00 69
>   00 6e 00 65 00 73 00 65 00 20 00 74 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 20 00 2d 4e
>   87 65 4b 6d d5 8b

which is in little-endian.

I ran the test code on Visual Studio 2013 and clang, respectively, and ended up with the same results.

So, why is the big-endian mode of `codecvt_utf8_utf16` doesn't have any effect on these conversions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same page you reference says the `little_endian` flag is for input only. The output is a sequence of codepoints, not a byte stream. Each codepoint is represented using whatever is normal for the platform - in your case little endian.

Your program is just telling you how a `char16_t` is represented in memory.